# Jquery toggle effects

Tags: jquery, toggle

How can I close the flyout  when the user click the other link, if the other flyout is open it should close and then the other flyout should open. Ie. one should close when the other opens. Also, if the user click on on the page the flyout should close.
thanks

Here is my code

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>


    <script language="javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){ 

       // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready 

       // (a little sooner than page load) 

        $('.slickbox').hide();

       // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link 

$('a.slick-toggle').click(function() { 
    $(this).next("div").find(".slickbox").toggle(400);
    return false;
}); 

      });

</script>     


<a href="#" class="slick-toggle"> link1</a>
<div style="position:relative; outline: 1px dashed orange; padding:0px;">
        <div class="slickbox" style=" outline: 1px dashed blue; width:300px;background-color:#ccc;position:absolute; top:10px; left: 20px;"> 
<ul id="flyoutmenu" >
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>


<a href="#" class="slick-toggle"> link2</a>
<div style="position:relative; outline: 1px dashed orange; ">
        <div class="slickbox" style=" outline: 1px dashed blue; width:300px;background-color:#ccc;position:absolute; top:10px; left: 20px;"> 
<ul id="flyoutmenu" >
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should really fix the ids to be unique between the both flyouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic concept where span is the child of div.

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $('span').hide();
    $('span', this).toggle();
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/DPMZ6/

Comment: How can i go about closing it? it stay open once clicked. I want it to close when the user clicks anywhere else in the page. - Thanks

Comment: In my example it closes when another link is clicked on. What are you referring to.

Comment: I was referring to when u click somewhere else on the page, The flyout doesnt close it stays open. How can this be closed? -thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    var mouse_is_inside = false;

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('.slickbox').hide();

    $('a.slick-toggle').click(function() {
        $("body").unbind('mouseup');
        closeOtherToggles();
        var obj = $(this).next("div").find(".slickbox");
        obj.toggle(400);
        catchOutsideClick(obj);
        return false;
    }); 
});

function closeOtherToggles(){
    $('div.slickbox').hide(400);
}

function catchOutsideClick(obj){
    obj.hover(function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=false; 
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){
        if(! mouse_is_inside){
            obj.hide(400);
        }
    });
}
```